# Django: How do I make a password input field in a model-form?

Tags: django, forms, models

I'm trying to make a basic Sign Up form that asks for a username, email address and password. The data needs to be saved into django-admin so according to my (limited) experience I need to embed the information in my models.py.

I'm basically just super confused as to how to implement the necessary widget (maybe a missing import or a built-in function?) in my models as well as how the field information in the models section has to differ from the field information in the forms.py section.

Here is my code for models.py:

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    user_name = models.CharField( max_length = 30, default = '', blank = False, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = models.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)
```

and here is the code I have for forms.py:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = SignUp
       fields = ['user_name', 'email', 'pass_word'] #specific order
       password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
       widgets = { 'password': forms.PasswordInput(),}
```

Comment: further research has shown that I could possibly use `pip install django-password-validation` in the terminal and make adjustments in the settings. Any ideas?

Comment: You must **absolutely not** do any of this. You are saving passwords in clear text, which is very dangerous. There is no need , in any case: Django has the built in contrib.auth model which deals with authentication.

Comment: (Although to answer your underlying question, the choice of widget is determined in the model form, which you have done; there is no reason to specify it in the model, let alone bring in some random third party library.)

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll look into it

Comment: If you need to add some fields to user model, you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser for that. Also, the confirm password should not be saved in your model, as it is just a double check to making sure that the password input is the intended one.